# Google Analytics double counting concern (http AND https reqs at the same time double counts?)

Tags: google-analytics

i have a website with GA, i set it up according to a tutorial from their site, basically its the copy paste code, but i added another account

`Ga('create','xxxx-1','auto');
Ga('create','yyyy-2','auto', 'acc2');
Ga('send', 'pageview');
Ga('acc2.send', 'pageview');`

In the network i *sometimes* see a http AND a https^a request and sometimes only a http^b or https^c.
I.e.

- scenario a i get 4 requests, 2 for each account
- Scenario b i get 2 requests, 1 for each ( this looks nirmal to me)
- Scenario c i get 2 requests again but from https (i again this looks
  normal to me)

So overall in 3 questions:

1. Is this normal? Why is it not consistent and always send one way.
2. Does http and https result in double counting??
3. Should ut send only from one? Http OR https?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is to install Google Analytics through Google tag manager. GTM allows a much better control over the firing rules (ie: you can set it to fire only when the dom is fully loaded for example).

Then, I'd recommend to install the add-on 'Google Analytics debugger' for chrome (made by Google: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). It will show you exactly what is sent to GA in the console and also highlight any problem with your configuration.

Finally, if your website support https you should not see page-views with 'http://' in GA. That could potentially mean that the https DNS redirect is not configured properly.

If you give me the URL of your site I am happy to have a look for you.

Best,

A.

Comment: Thanks! I ll have a look over the weekend. Also thanks for your offer to look it up, but I am proplably not allowed to